# Why does Option type try block require a type annotation?

Tags: rust

compiler: `rustc 1.71.0-nightly (c609da59d 2023-04-18)`

I tried nightly `#![feature(try_blocks)]` with this:

```rust
#![feature(try_blocks)]
fn test_try(input: Option<i32>) {
    let output = try {
        input?
    };

    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

But the compiler claims that `output` needed type annotations. Full error message is here:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     let output = try {
  |         ^^^^^^
  |
help: consider giving `output` an explicit type
  |
3 |     let output: /* Type */ = try {
  |               ++++++++++++
```

If I tried `let output: Option<i32> = ...` everything works fine.

It seems `output` should be `Option<i32>` but the compiler does not infer that.

Is it just because the feature is unstable or did I miss something? Any other type than `Option<i32>` is possible for `output`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `try_blocks` feature is mostly unstable because of inference problems. The design of the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait (that powers `try` blocks and the `?` operator) makes it very flexible, but also very hard for the compiler to infer the type.

In std there is nothing except `Option<i32>` that can be the result of this expression. But one can write one, because the thing that drives the desugaring of the `try` block is not the types that are `?`ed in it, but the type that it results to. So it can be anything, as long as it supports `?`ing `Option<i32>`. For example:

```rust
#![feature(try_blocks, try_trait_v2)]

use std::convert::Infallible;
use std::ops::ControlFlow;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyFancyType;

impl std::ops::FromResidual<Option<Infallible>> for MyFancyType {
    fn from_residual(_residual: Option<Infallible>) -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

impl std::ops::FromResidual for MyFancyType {
    fn from_residual(_residual: Infallible) -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

impl std::ops::Try for MyFancyType {
    type Output = i32;
    type Residual = Infallible;

    fn from_output(_output: i32) -> Self {
        Self
    }

    fn branch(self) -> ControlFlow<Self::Residual, Self::Output> {
        ControlFlow::Continue(0)
    }
}

fn test_try(input: Option<i32>) {
    let output: MyFancyType = try { input? };

    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=88c982c14ef681fdab5e9ad5d0e280b3).